# Changes made using pymysql don't "persist" to database

Tags: mysql, pymysql

I am trying to Insert Into a mysql database using pymysql. After the Insert and calling commit, as a demo, I Select and print all rows. The new row is printed, but - only the last added row is displayed (printed) and the auto_incremented Id field increments but only one row is displayed regardless of how many time I run the code. No rows are visible in mysql command line select or in the Sequel Pro "Contents" tab. I believe I have reviewed all the pertinent "Similar Questions"

Thanks.

```
import pymysql

connCost = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='*****', passwd='********', db='CU_COST')
testCur = connCost.cursor()
vF1 = 321
vF2 = '/zero#'
# Transaction implictily started?
query = "Insert Into testInsert (F1, F2) Values(" + str(vF1) + ", '" + vF2 +"')"
testCur.execute(query)
connCost.commit
testCur.execute("Select * From testInsert")
rows = testCur
for row in rows:
   print row

testCur.close
connCost.close
```

Result of print (after running the code 9 times):

```
2.7.5 (v2.7.5:ab05e7dd2788, May 13 2013, 13:18:45) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
Python Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
[evaluate testInsert2.py]
(9, 321, '/zero#')
```

Comment: I inadvertently deleted the line: "vF1 = 321" oops...

Comment: I added an explicit "Start Transaction" and "Commit" (using <cursor>.execute("Start Transaction")) and the changes seem to be persisting. I was assuming from research that MySql was implicitly starting a transaction and that using <connection>.commit would accomplish the same. How ever that does not seem to work for me. If I am missing something I'd love to hear. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Commit is a function. Therefore you must call it as such:

```
connCost.commit()
```

That should fix it.